# Translation of "This broadly falls"

Tags: traduction, anglais

> This broadly falls under the topic of kinematics of deformation.

Je pense *largement* interprète *broadly* mais quel mot ou quelle structure interprète **fall under** dans ce contexte ?

Comment: broadly : generally, without considering details; donc, possiblement : en gros, dans les grandes lignes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'expression verbale « tomber sous la coupe de » semble avoir un domaine d'application assez général et devrait convenir.

ADDITION

1. Il y a une autre possibilité qui reste dans le ton imagé de l'original : «  reposer sur » et qui signifie à peu près la même chose que la forme précédente.
2. Il peut y avoir à examiner le contexte soigneusement en traduisant cette tournure; le dictionnaire anglais donne la définition suivante : a) be classed among b) be subjected to. Donc, les deux formes données ci-dessus peuvent être employées s'il s'agit de (b) dans le contexte; ni l'une ni l'autre ne pourront être employées si le contexte est (a). 
   Si une traduction qui ne conserve pas l'esprit imagé de la phrase anglaise est souhaité le verbe « dépendre de » est utilisable  dans le contexte (b); un autre verbe très approprié dans ce contexte est le verbe « relever de »; ce  verbe est donné initialement dans la réponse de *nonobstant fascisme* et celui-ci est aussi utilisable dans le contexte (a).

Pour traduire le contexte (a) il faut d'autres verbes; ceux qui ont été considérés ci-dessus ne conviennent pas. Deux possibilité de base sont « faire partie de » et « être » ; cependant, vu le qualificatif utilisé (largement) il semble que le contexte (a) soit plus difficilement justifiable.

exemple :

- This principle falls under the theorie of quantum mechanics. -- « *Ce principe fait partie de la mécanique des quanta.* », « *C'est un principe de la mécanique des quanta.* ».

Le verbe « entrer dans », assez imagé, correspond très bien à l'original dans le contexte (a); cette addition est cependant due à *nonobstant fascisme*, dont j'ai pu lire la réponse avant d'écrire la présente addition.

Des tournures plus spécifiques dans leur niveau d'information peuvent avoir plus d'intérêt, comme par exemple « C'est une partie constitutive de la mécanique des quanta. »

Answer (score 3):

En ce qui a trait à la locution *falls under*, j'emploierais le verbe [*entrer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entrer) ou [*relever*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/relever) avec la préposition qui convient, pour signifier l'*appartenance à l'ensemble*, l'idée d'*être contenu dans* :

> Ça entre généralement dans la catégorie de... 
>  Ça relève
>   essentiellement de [tel sujet]...